# SQL server write a procedure call procedures in linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, rpc

i'm writing a procedure which calls many procedures in a linked server

i works fine if i just run  `exec [10.10.10.10].ContentDB.dbo.[sp_Copy_new_data]`

but when i try to write a procedure to call it, it will say:

```
The object name '10.10.10.10.ContentDB.dbo.sp_Copy_new_data' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.
```

code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Master_Caller

AS
BEGIN
.....
truncate table [10.10.10.10].ContentDB.dbo.[new_dataTable]
exec [10.10.10.10].ContentDB.dbo.[sp_Copy_new_data]
.....
END
```

This is a SQL server 2012.

Thanks

Comment: Cant you simply have a name for that server first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EXEC AT command to achieve what you want
Try this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Master_Caller

AS
BEGIN
.....
    EXEC ('truncate table ContentDB.dbo.[new_dataTable]') AT [10.10.10.10]
    EXEC ('EXEC ContentDB.dbo.[sp_Copy_new_data]') AT [10.10.10.10]
.....
END
```

Hope that helps